# Cannot get a configuration file of Analytics from Google's official page

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Now, I want to add Analytics to my Android app then I read [the official page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).

It says I must get a configuration file from the page. So I clicked the **GET A CONFIGURATION FILE** button. But nothing happens!

The loading circle animation is rolling forever!!!

[image: The loading circle animation is rolling forever!!!]

- I have a Developer account and an Analytics account and already logged in them.
- I'm using Chromium or Firefox on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

Comment: I am having the same issue, please let me know if you get it.

Comment: @Anjum My problem was solved. Liam's answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks @hata,  I will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing that worked for me was to go into the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and approve the new TOS. This is required before you can continue making project and configuration updates.

Unfortunately the site to generate JSON config files doesn't prompt us that it needs this in order to move forward.

Comment: Thank you! I've never visited the site. I always go only to **Google Play** Developer Console. Without approving any terms of service, it seems that just once I logged in the **Google** Developer Console, the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank you. This saved the day. Couldn't find a solution anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Now (January 3, 2016) I can get configuration file from Google Analytics after waiting for two days.

I just create a new property in Admin Panel, then follow the link of 'Getting started guide' in the landing page. It brings me to the get configuration file page

I don't think it is the only way to get the configuration file. So I back to access from the official page but now it work. I not sure this is an effect from my solution?

Hope this can help you.